# Numpy index without using slice

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have an array A whose shape is (4,3,2).
Is there anyway to represent something like A[:,1,1] or A[3,:,0] without using slice syntax?

Lets say I have a possibility table p(A,B,C) with a shape (4,3,2). Given two states of any two variables, I need to know the other variable's possibility table. But I don't know which two variables' states I will know in advance. So I can't use slicing syntax.

```
pABC=np.array([
    [[ 0.9 ,  0.3 ],
    [ 0.8 ,  0.4 ],
    [ 0.1 ,  0.01]],
   [[ 0.08,  0.05],
    [ 0.17,  0.05],
    [ 0.01,  0.01]],
   [[ 0.01,  0.05],
    [ 0.01,  0.15],
    [ 0.87,  0.97]],
   [[ 0.01,  0.6 ],
    [ 0.02,  0.4 ],
    [ 0.02,  0.01]]])
```

Sometimes I need to index [:,0,1], sometimes I need to index [2,:,0]. I need to write a function for this indexing operation. So I can't use slicing in my function because I don't know which axis I need to slice.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific what you are trying to do here? I can't really think of a situation where this would be useful.

Comment: @cel, Hi I revised the question. Is it clear enough now? Thanks!

Comment: Hmh, yes interesting problem. But I think this can be solved by normal splicing. `[:,0,1]` and `[2,:,0]` are both just special cases of `[x1:x2, y1:y2, z1:z2]`, where you have to find the right values for x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2

Comment: @thanks. I came up with this idea too but it seems like too trivial if the dimensions keep increasing. I hope there might be something like index along certain dimensions.

Comment: Okay, maybe I didn't get the problem then. Are you trying to generalize that to arbitrary dimensions? Note that you can also build slices with the `slice` method and then index your array with a tuple of those slices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @cel. It turns out slice() is exactly what I want.

":" in numpy is slice(None). So A[1,:,2] is equal to A[1,slice(None),2].

Then I can slice on any dimension I want.

Have fun!